# UIView Animation not working for Landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, uiviewanimation

I am using an UIView Animation where a second view appears from bottom and comes up to the center of the view. But it is not working in landscape mode although my app supports landscape mode and I implemented the method "willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation". Here is my code:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    imageView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 499, 320, 0)];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"trans.png"];
    [imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeBottom];



    [self.view addSubview:imageView];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                          delay:0.5f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^(void) {
                         imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 92, 320, 320);

                     }
                     completion:NULL];


}


-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    float pos_y, pos_x;
    pos_y = UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]) ? screen.size.width/2  : screen.size.height/2;
    pos_x = UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]) ? screen.size.height/2 : screen.size.width/2;

    imageView.center = CGPointMake(pos_x, pos_y);

}
```

I guess I´m setting the frame of the second view in the wrong place...

Answer (score 0):

You have used `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` but you have to use `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`.

`willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` will give you orientation before rotating.

So use this..........

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    imageView.center = self.view.center;
}
```

This will definitely help you...

Have a happy coding...........................         -:)